# Outlook can't parser multiple tables from html with pywin32

Tags: outlook, pywin32

I try to convert the html file to msg file, it stopped convert when meet third table tag in html.
I searched this question but didn't get any result -- it seems like only myself meet this problem.
So this is the example html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>This Email is using for understand outlook mail synthesis</h1>
    <h2>0001</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image001.jpg</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>
// stop parsing after parse this table
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="cid:image001.jpg" alt="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image002.jpg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="cid:image002.jpg" alt="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image003.jpg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="cid:image003.jpg" alt="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image004.jpg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="cid:image004.png" alt="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>No!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my python code:

```
from win32com import client as win32
import os

outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Subject = "This is a subject"

with open(".\\mix.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    html = f.read()

mail.HtmlBody = html

current_path = os.getcwd()
at = mail.Attachments.Add(current_path + "\\image001.jpg")
at.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "image001.jpg")
at = mail.Attachments.Add(current_path + "\\image002.jpg")
at.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "image002.jpg")
at = mail.Attachments.Add(current_path + "\\image003.jpg")
at.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "image003.jpg")
at = mail.Attachments.Add(current_path + "\\image004.png")
at.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "image004.png")
mail.SaveAs(current_path + "\\rst.msg")
```

This is what I see when I open the "rst.msg" file:
[stop parsing after parse the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj01i.jpg)

I deleted the table in second tr tag and run the python script, this is what I get:
[stop parsing again after parse the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF04E.jpg)
This is the html code I deleted the table in second tr tag:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>This Email is using for understand outlook mail synthesis</h1>
    <h2>0001</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image001.jpg</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image002.jpg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
// stop parsing after parse this table
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="cid:image002.jpg" alt="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image003.jpg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="cid:image003.jpg" alt="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is image004.jpg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="cid:image004.png" alt="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>No!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope you can help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by upgrading outlook version. In the new version, outlook can generate email as expected, but if you add some picture to the email used for html generating and save this email, then pictures are added to the email as appendix. If you send the email after generate it and before save it, the receiver can't see those appendix. That's what you might want.
Upgrading the outlook version is a way to solve this question.